# Hyperbolic functions calculator values differing from the graph

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I was exploring hyperbolic functions and noticed something weird while comparing the analytical definition (e^x+e^-x)/2 with the geometrical definition using the hyperbola x^2 - y^2 = 1. For the angle pi/6, using the analytical definition gives approximately 1.14 while using the geometrical definition gives 1.22.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: how do you arrive at either of the numerical values? (telling us the software or calculator used, as well as what you asked it to compute, would help.)

Comment: I used the windows calculator. To get 1.14 I just plugged pi/6 into the cosh function (verified by using the formula involving e) and I got 1.22 when I equated $x/root(3)$ to $root(x^2−1)$

Comment: And why did you equate $x / \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{x^2 -1}$? Were you looking at some variant of [this diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#/media/File:Hyperbolic_functions-2.svg)? The value $a/2$ refers to the area of the shaded region, not the angle.

Comment: Yes exactly that. I figured out the problem, the area and the angle are different. Is there some relation between them?

Comment: $$A(\theta) = \int_0^\theta (\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2\theta)^{-1/2}d\theta$$ Though if you evaluate that integral you will just get something involving the inverse hyperbolic functions.